# AngularJS modify $scope inside interceptor

Tags: angularjs

How can i modify a `$scope` variable inside an interceptor?

```
var portal = angular.module('portal', ['ngResource', 'ui.utils', 'ngRoute']).config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
        return {
            responseError: function(rejection) {
                if(rejection.status == -1) {
                    // i want to modify this variable to true / false
                    $scope.restApiServerOnline = false;
                    return;
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    });
});
```

The purpose of the above code is to intercept all HTTP post / get made to the REST server, and if it fails, toggle this scope variable.

Comment: i dont think its possible to inject current scope in interceptors, why do u need to update the scope?

Answer (score 3):

I would look at including `$rootScope` in your config injection, eg:

```
function($httpProvider, $rootScope) {
```

Then set something like `$rootScope.restApiServerOnline = false;` as by the context of the variable, it appears you would like to access that globally anyway.